# React create subscriptionusing paypal smart button showing error ===>Do not pass both createSubscription and createOrder

Tags: reactjs, paypal-subscriptions

React Using create order and create subscription both using paypal smart button .Paypal subscription showing error ===>Do not pass both createSubscription and createOrder

```
<PayPalButton
    createSubscription = {(data:any, actions:any) => {
        return actions.subscription.create({
            'plan_id': 'P-2UF78835G6983425GLSM44MA'
        });
      }}
    onApprove={(data:any, actions:any)=> {

            alert('You have successfully created subscription ' + data.subscriptionID);
        }
    }
/>
```